# Find principal part of Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

Find principal part of Laurent series:

$$f(z)= \frac{1}{\sin z + \sinh z - 2z}$$

I calculate it and I have something like this:

$$\frac{1}{\dfrac{2z^5}{5!}+\dfrac{2z^9}{9!}+\cdots}$$ and don't know what to do next...

Comment: Write the denominator as $\frac{2z^5}{5!}\bigl(1+\frac{z^4}{9!/5!} + \dotsc\bigr)$. Does that give you an idea?

Comment: Not really. I don't know which is the next step and I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Think geometric series.

Comment: something like $\frac{z^{4n}}{a_n}$ ?

Comment: If you look at $$\frac{1}{1 + az^4 + bz^8 + \dotsc}$$ thinking of geometric series, can you see something?

Comment: the sum is $\frac{1}{1-cz}$ but then I have $\frac{5!(1-z^4)}{2x^5}$

Comment: Ok, i'm in the black hole with this exercise.

Comment: Let $w = az^4 + bz^8 + \dots$. Then $\frac{1}{1+w} =\,?$ How far do you need to go to get the principal part of $\frac{5!}{2z^5}\cdot \frac{1}{1+w}$?

Comment: Okay. So we have $\frac{1}{1+w} = 1-w + w^2 - w^3 + \dotsc$. Now recall that $w = az^4 + b z^8 + \dotsc$. Then we look at $1 - (az^4 + bz^8 + \dotsc) + (az^4 + bz^8 + \dotsc)^2 - \dotsc$. How much of that do you need to get the principal part when you multiply that with $\frac{60}{z^5}$?

Answer (score 1):

Just following the comments, it is clear that we just need the Taylor series of:
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2 z^{4n}}{(4n+5)!}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n\tag{1}$$
till the term $a_4 z^4$. By evaluating the LHS and the RHS at $z=0$ we get $a_0=60$, and since the LHS is $g(z^4)$ for some analytic function $g$, we have $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. Moreover:
$$ \frac{1}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2 z^{4n}}{(4n+5)!}} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{5!}+\frac{2z^4}{9!}\right)\left(1+O(z^8)\right)}=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{5!}+\frac{2z^4}{9!}}\left(1+O(z^8)\right)\tag{2}$$
so:
$$f(z)=60\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z^4}{3024}}\left(1+O(z^8)\right)=60\left(1-\frac{z^4}{3024}\right)\left(1+O(z^8)\right)\tag{3} $$
leads to $\color{red}{a_4=-\frac{5}{252}}$.